# How to get the glyph size of a font?

Tags: layout, solaris, x11, font-size

Under Solaris 8, CDE, I want to write a script that displays two or more applications on a screen, with a 5% margin. The method depends on the -geometry argument, which we're ok with. This needs to be able to be resolution independent, and that's turning out to be a problem.

Some of the applications (dtterm/xterm), measure the -geometry argument in characters instead of the usual pixels. I need to be able to understand which font it is going to display with, and the size of the glyphs so I can convert my pixel-centric layout to a character-centric one.

Any ideas how I can get this information systematically, or ideas for a different approach entirely?

Answer (score 0):

The font that `xterm` can be changed both via X resources read at start and through the Ctrl-click menu at runtime:

```
! ~/.Xdefaults
xterm*font: fixed
```

[image: http://www.xcat.org/doc/1.x/xcat-HOWTO_files/screen_shot_xterm_font_change_2.jpg]
<sub>(source: [xcat.org](http://www.xcat.org/doc/1.x/xcat-HOWTO_files/screen_shot_xterm_font_change_2.jpg))</sub>

I don't think it is possible in general to fix the window size; each application is free to interpret `-geometry` in any way it wants.